# addeventListener not working on all elements

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Hello I mam facing a problem with my script.

I am beginner in JS and I am trying to add event listener to buttons generated by a foreach but only the last button generated is responding to the addeventlistener.

I am also facing a pb of variable range with the getLocation(flight) function which is returning undefined outside the fuction while the console.log in the function is displaying the good variable value.

Can someone help?

HTML:

```
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Airbus Max</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind:wght@300;400;500;600;700&family=PT+Sans+Narrow:wght@400;700&family=PT+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Info-vols : Le site de l'info des vols !</h1>
        <h2>Besoin d'informations au sujet d'un vol? Vous êtes au bon endroit!</h2>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div id="flex-content">
            <div id="pretty-line">
            </div>
            <div id="tableau-des-vols-container">
                <div id="tableau-des-vols">
                    <div id="flex-display">
                        <div id="liste-vols-container">
                            <h2>Liste des vols</h2>
                            <div id="formulaire">
                                <form>
                                    <label>Chercher par numéro de vol: </label><input>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <table id="tableau">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th id="num">Numéro de vol</th>
                                        <th id="lat">Provenance</th>
                                        <th id="long">Ville de départ</th>
                                        <th id="meteo"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="body">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div id="meteo">
                            <h2 class="titre-meteo">Météo du vol sélectionné</h2>
                            <div class="bloc-logo-info">
                                <div class="bloc-logo">
                                    <img src="./ressources/jour/04d.svg" alt="logo du temps qu'il fait" class="logo-meteo">
                                </div>
                                <div class="bloc-info">
                                    <p class="temps"></p>
                                    <p class="temperature"></p>
                                    <p class="localisation"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>

    </footer>

    <script type="module" src="includes/scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCOK0Q1fbQOWFCuumTw9uc3G05WKFD9zdY"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
let resultatAPIMeteo;

let long;
let lat;
let buttonId;

const URL = "https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?lamin=45.8389&lomin=5.9962&lamax=47.8229&lomax=10.5226";
const TITREMETEO = document.querySelector('.titre-meteo');
const IMG = document.querySelector('.bloc-logo');
const temps = document.querySelector('.temps');
const temperature = document.querySelector('.temperature');
const localisation = document.querySelector('.localisation');
const tbody = document.querySelector(('#body'));

let flights = [];
let table = document.getElementById("tableau");

AppelAPI();

function AppelAPI() {
    fetch(URL)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then((data) => {
            let i = 0;

            getFlights(data);
            console.log(data)
            console.log(flights)

            flights.forEach(flight => {
                let i = flights.indexOf(flight)
                console.log(flight);
                long = flight[5];
                lat = flight[6];

                let city = getLocation(flight);
                console.log("city: " + city);

                let meteoDepart = "test";
                let meteoArrivee = "test";

                /* let newRow = document.createElement('tr');
                let newFlightNumber = document.createElement('td');
                let newflightNumberText = flight[1];
                let newProvenance = document.createElement('td');
                let newProvenanceText = flight[2];
                let newCity = document.createElement('td');
                let newCityText = city;


                tbody.append(newRow);

                newFlightNumber.textContent = newflightNumberText;
                newRow.append(newFlightNumber);

                newProvenance.textContent = newProvenanceText;
                newRow.append(newProvenance);

                newCity.textContent = newCityText;
                newRow.append(newCity); */
                

                if(i % 2 === 0) {
                    table.innerHTML += `<tr class='pair'>\n` +
                        "    <td>" + flight[1] + "</td>\n" +
                        "    <td>" + flight[2] + "</td>\n" +
                        `    <td>${city}</td>\n` +
                        `    <td><button id="tr-${i}"  onclick="alert('Bouton cliqué')">Météo</button></td>`+
                        "</tr>\n";
                } else {
                    table.innerHTML += `<tr class='pair'>\n` +
                        "    <td>" + flight[1] + "</td>\n" +
                        "    <td>" + flight[2] + "</td>\n" +
                        `    <td>${city}</td>\n` +
                        `    <td><button id="tr-${i}"  onclick="alert('Bouton cliqué')">Météo</button></td>`+
                        "</tr>\n";
                }
                console.log('tr-'+i);
                let button = document.getElementById('tr-'+i);
                tbody.style.color='white';
                button.style.backgroundColor='orange';

                button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                    console.log('from api: click');
                    AppelApiMeteo(flight);
                });
                i++;
            })
        })
}

function AppelApiMeteo(flight) {
    console.log('from apimeteo: click');

    let lattitude = flight[6];
    let longitude = flight[5];
    let URLMeteo = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lattitude}&lon=${longitude}&exclude=minutely&units=metric&lang=fr&appid=${CLEAPIMETEO}`;
    console.log(URLMeteo);
    fetch(URLMeteo)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            resultatAPIMeteo = data;

            TITREMETEO.innerHTML = `Météo du vol ${flight[1]} en provenance de ${flight[2]}`;
            IMG.innerHTML = `<img src="./ressources/jour/${resultatAPIMeteo.current.weather[0].icon}.svg" alt="logo du temps qu'il fait" className="logo-meteo">`;
            temps.innerText = resultatAPIMeteo.current.weather[0].description;
            temperature.innerText = `${Math.trunc(resultatAPIMeteo.current.temp)}°`;
            localisation.innerText = resultatAPIMeteo.timezone;

            console.log('meteo data:' + resultatAPIMeteo.current.weather[0].description);
        })
}

function getFlights(data) {
    console.log(data.states);
    data.states.forEach(element =>{
        flights.push(element)
    })
}

function getLocation(flight){
    let lattitude = flight[6];
    let longitude = flight[5];
    let geocoder;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    let latlng = {
        lat: parseFloat(lattitude),
        lng: parseFloat(longitude),
    };

    geocoder
        .geocode({location: latlng})
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("pos: " + response.results[7].address_components[0].long_name);
            return response.results[7].address_components[0].long_name;
        })
        .catch((e) => window.alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + e));
}
/*
let row = document.createElement('tr')
let columnNum = document.createElement('th');
let columnLat = document.createElement('th');
let columnLong = document.createElement('th');
let columnMeteo = document.createElement('th')

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    columnNum.textContent = resultatsAPI[i].icao24;

    table.appendChild(row);
    row.appendChild(columnNum);
    row.appendChild(columnLat);
    row.appendChild(columnLong);
    row.appendChild(columnMeteo);


    console.log('test:' + resultatsAPI[i].icao24);
}
*/
```

Comment: One problem per question, and please make this an actual [mcve] that only covers that one problem -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: why use this  `let i = flights.indexOf(flight)` strange method and instead don't use directly `flights.forEach((flight, i) =>{` ?

Comment: oh yes sorry that was to try if it was a problem with the variable i but finally its not

Comment: ok Andreas sorry i m gonna edit